# How do I disable hardware acceleration in windows 7 without removing driver?

Tags: windows-7, hardware-acceleration

I have a laptop that does not render hardware accelerated stuff. The problem is in the chip. Tested under many drivers and operating systems.

My question is: How do I disable hardware acceleration, without removing the nVidia driver?

As said [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/131543-disable-hardware-acceleration.html), there is no way to disable it. I do not want to loose the stuff offered by nVidia (color correction and stuff) but I cannot use it in video rendering etc. Of cource aero is disabled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the more relevant question, and the one you should be asking instead, is WHY "does [my laptop] not render hardware accelerated stuff?"

Comment: It's a hardware failure. Verified. I am lucky enough to have the "not"-accelerated-part of the GPU intact.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to disable exactly? Hardware video decode or hardware video processing or rendering? Video decode is codec specific and DXVA can be disabled via the registry. I don't understand what you mean by "does not render hardware accelerated stuff" - do you mean the rendering isn't hardware accelerated?

Comment: Hardware acceleration in Display Adapter level. Meaning that I don't want it to be enabled. Similar in WindowsXp like this http://www.mindmedia.nl/CMS/images/stories/Support/Knowledge_Base/how_to_hardware_acceleration_in_windows_xp_en/Picture03.png